# Is there an option to tell SSMS not to use the OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY flag when generating scripts?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

SSMS has started including the flag `OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF` when generating table creation scripts. These scripts then fail when attempting to deploy the DB project from Visual Studio.

While I can manually remove the flag from each of the scripts I was wondering if there's a setting in SSMS so that it doesn't reference that flag at all (whether off or on)?

Comment: "Set Scripting Options" -> "Advanced" -> "Script for Server Version" and then select SQL Server 2017 or lower. There are no options to tell SSMS to not script things unless they deviate from the defaults, unfortunately, so you can't selectively exclude options this way.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks, that worked. Although setting it to SQL Server 2017 still generated the `OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY` flag  for some reason. I had to set it to SQL Server 2014. If you answer the question with your comment I'll mark it accepted.

Comment: Huh, that sounds like an SSMS bug -- `OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY` is a 2019 feature, as far as I know, and it should know this.

Comment: You're deploying from Visual Studio?   There are also deployment options for a a database project in Visual Studio which are more detailed than the SSMS options - you should go through them as well to check you are targeting the correct deployment options